# paths not being consistent python django

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail, import

I'm trying to import sorl-thumbnail into my app in django. Now the way that I have the site set up, using mod_wsgi on CentOS 5 with cpanel, the path for the apps must have the project name when importing... which is a pain.

Obviously this is a cause of concern with portability of the app. I'm importing sorl-thumbnail, in previous apps I've just added sorl.thumbnail to the installed apps and it's worked.

However now it's causing issues unless I have the project name `www.` in front of the import path. It's never done this before and I can't seem to get around the path issue.

I've added `www.sorl.thumbnail` also but then the rest of the paths in the `sorl` files have errors. Any ideas on how to remedy this or fix a work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use the project name when importing - just make sure that the apps are somewhere on your python path. Something along the lines of:

```
sys.path.append('/etc/django/domains/mydomain.com/myproject/')
```

... in your .wsgi file should do it (with the path to your own project, of course).

Ideally reusable apps should be outside of your project directory anyway, so consider creating a folder such as '/etc/django/lib/' to contain reusable apps and appending that to sys.path in your wsgi handler too.

Or, if you don't like that, perhaps use virtualenv and add your reusable apps directly to site-packages.

Or, if you don't like that, put your reusable apps somewhere else and symlink them to site-packages or somewhere on your python path.

In short, just make sure the package/module you're importing is on your python path. If you find yourself adding the project name or 'www' to a bunch of import paths, then you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: very well explained and you have given great options for me to follow... very useful information too, so thanks very much for taking the time to write this.